# pinterest button stopped working on Blogspot site

Tags: javascript, blogger, pinterest, blogspot

I had successfully implemented the pinterest pin it button on my site, but it has recently stopped working. Could anyone tell me why?

My website is http://www.lookbookcookbook.com and I am using the following code

```
<div class='w2bPinitButton' expr:id='&quot;w2bPinit-&quot; + data:post.id' style='display: none;visibility: hidden;height: 0;width:0;overflow: hidden;'> 
<data:post.body/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    w2bPinItButton({ 
        url:&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;, 
        thumb: &quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;, 
        id: &quot;<data:post.id/>&quot;, 
        defaultThumb: &quot;http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YZe-IcKvGRA/T8op1FIjwYI/AAAAAAAABg4/j-38UjGnQ-Q/s1600/w2b-no-thumbnail.jpg&quot;, 
        pincount: &quot;horizontal&quot; 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have managed to sort out your issue?

If not this link may be helpful or to others that want to implement it in their Blogspot site.

```
http://www.way2blogging.org/2012/06/add-dynamic-pinterest-pin-it-button-for-blogger-blogspot.html
```

Comment: ah yes, pinterest changed their script, so it needed to be updated.